# Trouble using NPM package in Laravel application

Tags: laravel, npm, webpack, laravel-mix, remove.bg

I've been using Laravel for years, but I've never used NPM packages in my Laravel apps until now. I'm using Laravel Valet as my development environment.

I am trying to utilize a simple package that interfaces with the [remove.bg js package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/remove.bg) but I can't get it working after hours of trying different things.

Here's what I've done:

1. Installed the package via `npm install remove.bg`.
2. The package was complaining that it couldn't find the modules that it depended on (unirest, http, etc), so I installed them via `npm install` and even added these fallbacks since it was complaining about Webpack 5 and polyfill:

My webpack.mix.js file:

```
mix.webpackConfig({
    resolve: {
        fallback: {
            fs: require.resolve('browserify-fs'),
            crypto: require.resolve('crypto-browserify'),
            stream: require.resolve('stream'),
            http: require.resolve('stream-http'),
            https: require.resolve('https-browserify'),
            path: require.resolve('path-browserify'),
            zlib: require.resolve('browserify-zlib'),
        },
    },
});
```

3. In my `resources/js/bootstrap.js` I added:

```
import { RemoveBgResult, RemoveBgError, removeBackgroundFromImageBase64 } from 'remove.bg';
window.Removebg = require('remove.bg');
```

4. Run `npm run dev` with no errors.
5. Included `<script src="{{ mix('/js/app.js') }}"></script>` in my blade template.

However, when I view my page, I get these errors in the console:

```
app.js:137237 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'prototype')
    at Object.inherits (app.js:137237)
    at Object../node_modules/browserify-zlib/lib/index.js (app.js:28688)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:139212)
    at Object../node_modules/unirest/index.js (app.js:131192)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:139212)
    at Object../node_modules/remove.bg/dist/index.js (app.js:108502)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:139212)
    at Module../resources/js/bootstrap.js (app.js:16242)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:139212)
    at Object../resources/js/app.js (app.js:16230)
```

I'm stumped. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Is the JS actually being prepared by that mix config?  You seem to have lost the instruction to actually build it - `mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')`

Comment: Yes, sorry. I just omitted it for brevity. This is what is there:

``mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js').postCss('resources/css/app.css', 'public/css', [ require('tailwindcss')]);``

Comment: @Mark I believe that should run on the server, not client browser. NodeJS and Laravel are both server side technologies, using the two in conjunction doesn't really make much sense without a little understanding of what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: do you look in app.js on 137237? What code is there?

Comment: Does your `app.js` still include the `require('./bootstrap')` line?

Comment: @Rory, Yes, it does.

Answer (score 1):

You can missed on webpack.mix.js file

Add this line

```
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js');
```

Comment: That's in there